"Select all/Apply all" option in Facet item for checkbox widget
I am using "Facet-Version: 2.0.7" and "Search API : 8.x-1.34" modules to display the site data using Ajax Filtering in my site. Now I need the functionality "select all/Apply all" option in Facet item for checkbox widget settings similar to "Show reset link". This "select all/Apply all" option is to select all the checkbox in particular Facet item and filter the result uisng Ajax.
Let me know how to do this functionality, is there any module available?. Site Drupal 10.2.5. Thanks in Advance

Facet source option:

